# indentation with eslint on jsx

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

I'm trying to make simple component. But when I click on `ctrl + s` it does this:

[image]

warning and error is this:

> [eslint] Expected closing tag to match indentation of opening.
>   (react/jsx-closing-tag-location) [eslint] Expected indentation of 4
>   space characters but found 2. (react/jsx-indent)

my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "max-len": ["warn", 120],
    "indent": ["warn", 2],
    "react/jsx-indent": ["warn", 4],
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-console": 0,
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "comma-dangle": [2, {
      "arrays": "never",
      "objects": "always",
      "imports": "never",
      "exports": "never",
      "functions": "ignore"
    }]
  },
  "globals": {
    "localStorage": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another formatter - like prettier - enabled?

Answer (score -1):

In your gif the  never closes with the same indentation. That should do it:

```
const App = () => (
  <button>
    <span>asd</span>
  </button>
)
```

In your gif you have either

```
const App = () => (
   <button>
     <span>asd</span>
     </button>
)
```

or

```
const App = () => (
     <button>
       <span>asd</span>
   </button>
)
```

Comment: How does that help?